# Why does Wonka speak French and German?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, dialogue, willy-wonka-and-chocolate-factory

In "Willy Wonka and the Chocolate Factory", why does Wonka speak French when he's introducing his guests to the Boat and why does he speak German when he's opening the Inventing Room Door?

Comment: Partial duplicate of [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/75531/46980), which asks specifically about the Inventing Room scene.

Comment: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/eccentric

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica It's about both. The actual body of the question asks "What did he say and why did he say it in German?". However, the answer doesn't apply to the bit where he speaks French, hence why it's only a *partial* duplicate.

Comment: Because he's a weird guy so he decided to speak in another language to confuse people.

Comment: In the book I am sure it refers to Wonka travelling the world looking for chocolate recipes which is why he ends up finding the oompa loompa tribe. So he answer would be he is well travelled?

Comment: Tour guides often make announcements in multiple languages.

Answer (score -1):

Wonka has narcissistic personality disorder, he is simply showing off his ability to speak multiple languages by showing he’s well versed in languages through his endeavors of searching the world for the finest chocolate recipes.